# Trying to get a return statement to be formatted as list and then used by a class and then run through if statements

Tags: python, class, return

```
while True:
    n=float(raw_input('Please enter your ID '))
    if n in range (1000,10000):

        break
    print 'ID is incorrect, please try again'

with open("txt.txt") as searchfile: #searching for book
    found = False
    while not found:
        b=str(raw_input('please enter a book '))
        if b == '':
            break  # allow the search-loop to quit on no input
        for line in searchfile:
            if b in line:
                print line 
              found = True
              break
      else:
          print 'Please try again'
          searchfile.seek(0)  # reset file to the beginning for next search
class books:
    '''class that supplys books to those who need them most'''
  def __init__(self,ID_number,book_title, author,avaliable):
      self.ID_number=ID_number
      self.book_title=book_title
      self.author=author
      self.avaliable=avaliable

  def description(self):
      print '%s %s %s %s'%         (self.ID_number,self.book_title,self.author,self.avaliable)
  def __getitem__(self,i):
      return self.availiable[i]
    print searchfile[3]
  def is_avaliable(self):
      if self.avaliable==0:
          print 'taken'
      else:
          print 'you can have me'

lis = searchfile #using result from searching for book
book_1 = books(lis[0], lis[1], lis[2], lis[3])
book_1.description()
book_1.is_avaliable()
```

I have this code, the first section is working fine, but i was trying to get it so that the result of my first section, regarding the searching for book section, with the printed output as a list.i was trying to access that list in my later code and then use it in the class section. So far it reads the through and returns this:

> TypeError: 'file' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Answer (score 1):

Your `lis = searchfile` line assigns the (now closed) file descriptor `searchfile` to `lis` You then try to access indices from it. I'm assuming what you want instead is:

```
def search():
    with open('txt.txt') as searchfile:
        while True:
            b = str(raw_input('please enter a book '))
            if b == '':
                break  # allow the search-loop to quit on no input
            for line in searchfile:
                if b in line:
                    return line  # return your line here!!
            else:
                print 'Please try again'
                searchfile.seek(0)  # reset file to the beginning for next search
        return None

lis = search()  # lis is now the line that the book is found at
# the rest of your code as written
...
```

Comment: This seems to let it run through the top part of the code, but when it gets below 'return none' it doesnt seem to be running through the classes as it was when i had the classes separate and working... before it would open the return value as the full list, now it is opening just the number of the book entered...

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're trying to do, then? The code you posted doesn't create a list anywhere.

Comment: What i was trying to do was once the book details had been accessed using the return function, then that return value saved as a list... using the saved list and accessing each element, eg: say you have the list '1,Book_1,Author_1,0' you would be able to access each individual part of the list using the code and then if part 3 was 0 then it would return book taken... if that makes more sense ?